# Snowflake: create a default field value that auto increments for each primary key, resets per primary key

Tags: sql, database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to create a table to house the following type of data

```
+--------+-----+----------+
| pk     | ctr | name     |
+--------+-----+----------+
| fish   |  1  | herring  |
| mammal |  1  | dog      |
| mammal |  2  | cat      |
| mammal |  3  | whale    |
| bird   |  1  | penguin  |
| bird   |  2  | ostrich  |
+--------+----_+----------+
```

PK is the primary key string (100) not null
ctr is a field I want to auto increment by 1 for each pk row

I have tried the following

```
create or replace  table schema.animals (
pk string(100) not null primary key,
ctr integer not null default  ( select NVL(max(ctr),0) + 1 from schema.animals )
name string (1000) not null);
```

This produced the following error

> SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 52 aggregate functions
>   are not allowed as part of the specification of a default value
>   clause.

So i would have used the auto increment /identity property like so

```
AUTOINCREMENT | IDENTITY [ ( start_num , step_num ) | START num INCREMENT num ]
```

but it doesnt seem to be able to support the resetting per unique pk

looking for any suggestions on how to solve this, thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with an `IDENTITY` method. The suggested solution is to use `INSTEAD OF` trigger that will calculate `ctr` value on every row of `INSERTED` table. For example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.animals ( 
   pk nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, 
   ctr integer NOT NULL,
   name nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_animals PRIMARY KEY (pk, ctr)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.animals_before_insert ON dbo.animals INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   INSERT INTO animals (pk, ctr, name)
   SELECT
      i.pk,
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.pk ORDER BY i.name) + ISNULL(a.max_ctr, 0)) AS ctr,
      i.name
   FROM inserted i
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT pk, MAX(ctr) AS max_ctr FROM dbo.animals GROUP BY pk) a
           ON i.pk = a.pk;
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.animals (pk, name) VALUES 
('fish'   , 'herring'),
('mammal' , 'dog'),
('mammal' , 'cat'), 
('mammal' , 'whale'), 
('bird'   , 'pengui'),
('bird'   , 'ostrich');

SELECT * FROM dbo.animals;
```

Result

```
pk      ctr   name
------- ----- ---------
bird    1     ostrich
bird    2     pengui
fish    1     herring
mammal  1     cat
mammal  2     dog
mammal  3     whale
```

Another method is to use scalar user-defined function as DEFAULT value but it is slow: the trigger fires once on all rows whereas the function is called on every row.

Comment: snowflake doesnt support triggers which makes things more difficult

Comment: @JayRizzi ah ok, it's DBMS-specific, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would have a column called `pk` that *is not* the primary key.  You cannot (easily) do what you want.  I would recommend doing this as:

```
create or replace table schema.animals (
    animal_id int identity primary key,
    name string(100) not null primary key,
);

create view schema.v_animals as
     select a.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by animal_id) as ctr
     from schema.animals a;
```

That is, calculate `ctr` when you need to use it, rather than storing it in the table.

Comment: pk is the primary key, its unfortunately a string, following a design doc given to me

Comment: @JayRizzi . . . `pk` s a component of a compound primary key.  Hence, "it" is not the primary key.